# how to add toggle button beside text in menu option

Tags: android, button, menu

I am trying to place button beside to the text in menus but as we have option to place only items in android,how can i place button and text in horizontal view in menus.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: unclear what you asking its good if you share any image what exactly you want and **BTW** what did you tried so far

Comment: you should add action view in menu item and create your own layout to add any view.

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom layout in menu item, [this link](https://stablekernel.com/using-custom-views-as-menu-items/) give you all details how to set custom menu.

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_alerts_menu_item"
        android:title="Alerts"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/view_alertsbadge" <!-- important part -->
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

Comment: While links are always welcome on this site, it is important to provide contextual information to why the link is important. The same goes for code. You should always try to explain why the code will solve the problem of the question.